# Get Hard Disk Size dynamically in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to get the the size of the main HD. Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:@"/" error:nil];
```

But this code doesn't give me the correct size of the HD. If my HD has a capacity of 320gb that will return 290GB. I think there are other volumes but I don't know how to calculate them.

What I want to know is a way to get the total size of my hard drive.

Comment: What do you mean “main HD”? I have one drive with my startup disk (one partition per OS, plus another) and one drive with my Home folder. Which of these is the “main” hard drive?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: isn't 290GB what you can use due to filesystem overhead costs? I have 120GB and it shows me 114,6GB, so not the real size

Comment: @Marek, yes, I'd like to know the actual real size

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting the correct answer, actually. People who sell hard drives like to use the power-of-10 *giga*byte to describe the capacity of the disk, while the computer itself cares about how many multiples of 2 are available, and displays the *gibi*bytes. A [gibibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) is bigger than a gigabyte. The [SI prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix) "giga-" means 10<sup>9</sup>; the so-called [binary prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) "gibi-" was chosen to be the closest power of two, 2<sup>30</sup>, which is 1,073,741,824.

The true number of bytes is the same in either case, it's just reported differently depending on whether you divide by 1,000,000,000 or 1,073,741,824. For example, 320,000,000,000 ÷ 1,073,741,824 = 298.023, and you might lose a bit more to area the disk reserves for itself.

Comment: That's a very thoughtful and useful anser. Thanks!